# can't push app to heroku, even though app updated to ruby 2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, heroku-cli

I get the following error when I do git push heroku master for my ruby app.

```
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 
--retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3- 
external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby- 
2.3.8.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 1 of 3.
remote:        Command: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 
--retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3- 
external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/heroku-18/ruby- 
2.3.8.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed on attempt 2 of 3.
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.8
remote:  !     
remote:  !     This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18. 
The minimum supported version
remote:  !     of Ruby on the Heroku-18 stack can found at:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby- 
support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

I've updated my ruby version and have set ruby 2.5.1 to default

```
rvm list
=* ruby-2.5.1 [ x86_64 ]

'=>' - current
'=*' - current && default
'*' - default
```

I am on the most recent ruby version

> ruby -v
>
> ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]

My gemfile is also up-to-date

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails',        '5.1.6'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.12'
gem 'faker',        '1.7.3'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. The problem was that I hadn't successfully added and committed my changes even though I've updated my app to 2.5.1

Have to:
git add -A
git commit -m "random message about updating app to 2.5.1"
git push heroku master